# Working with Emails (POP3, IMAP, SMTP e.t.c) in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, mnesia, yaws, nitrogen

How can one handle email related communications pragmatically in Erlang/OTP? 
Using bash, python or Perl scripts, its possible for one to send out emails. However, in Erlang, i have not yet found an Application or built in function dedicated to sending and/or receiving emails on behalf of other applications.

In **[yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/)**, there is a mail application located in the applications path of the web server.However, on the yaws home page, there is no documentation dedicated to this application. In **[Nitrogen Web framework](http://www.nitrogenproject.com)**, i have found nothing yet useful as far as email protocols are concerned.

If any one knows of a library which i can use for sending and/or receiving mails pragmatically, could please direct me. Also there could be unofficial implementations as well that i do not know of.
thanks, in advance

Comment: You accept an answer for the questions that you have asked. You click on the symbol close to the votes on the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been successfully using [smtp_fsm.erl](https://github.com/ahmednawras/log4erl/blob/master/src/smtp_fsm.erl) for sending emails (not exactly this version, but this one is publicly accessible).

Quick search showed some other smtp- and email-related packages, but I don't have experience with any of these.

- https://github.com/Vagabond/gen_smtp
- https://github.com/archaelus/esmtp
- https://github.com/tonyg/erlang-smtp

Comment: @Muzaaya: You can select this answer as accepted if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **send** emails with Erlang, you should take a look at the transactional email service [AlphaMail](http://amail.io).

Here is an example of how to send an email with the [AlphaMail module for Erlang](https://github.com/comfirm/alphamail-erlang-client):

```
Service = alphamail:email_service("YOUR-ACCOUNT-API-TOKEN-HERE").
Payload = alphamail:message_payload(
    2,                                                                          % Project id
    alphamail:email_contact(<<"Sender Name">>, <<"from@example.com">>),         % Sender
    alphamail:email_contact(<<"Joe E. Receiver">>, <<"to@example.org">>, 1234), % Receiver (with receiver id)
    % Any JSON serializable payload data
    [
        {"userId", 1234},
        {"name", {struct, [
            {"first", "Joe"},
            {"last", "E. Receiver"},
        ]}},
        {"dateOfBirth", 1989}
    ]
).
alphamail:queue(Service, Payload).
```

And as your HTML/[Comlang](http://app.amail.io/#/docs/comlang/) template:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <b>Name:</b> <# payload.name.first " " payload.name.last #><br>
        <b>Date of Birth:</b> <# payload.dateOfBirth #><br>

        <# if (payload.userId != null) { #>
            <a href="/sign-up">Sign Up Free!</a>
        <# } else { #>
            <a href="/login?id=<# payload.userId #>">Sign In</a>
        <# } #>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Disclosure: I'm one of the developers behind AlphaMail**

Comment: I think your "to" syntax is wrong -- the receiver id should be the last parameter?

Comment: I've updated the example with the correct syntax (with the receiver id as the 3rd parameter).